# nsIProcess with arg with quote not getting created

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm trying to run a little routine to convert some .doc Word files (using LibreOffice) to HTML. When I run it on the command line, it works, but not through `nsIProcess`:

```
var Cc = Components.classes;
var Ci = Components.interfaces;

var sofficePath = ('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\LibreOffice 4.0\\program\\soffice.exe').replace(/"/g, '');
var path = 'C:\\Users\\Brett\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\brl-downloader6.doc';
function createProcess (path, args) {
    var aNsIFile = Cc['@mozilla.org/file/local;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsILocalFile);
    aNsIFile.initWithPath(path);

    var process = Cc['@mozilla.org/process/util;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsIProcess);
    process.init(aNsIFile);
    process.runAsync(args, args.length, null);
}
createProcess(sofficePath, [
    '--headless', '-convert-to', 'html:"HTML (StarWriter)"', path.replace(/"/g, '')
]);
```

I think it is related to the quotation mark in the `html:"HTML (StarWriter)"` argument, but I'm not sure how to get around it.

I also tried this to no effect (single or double quotes give errors from LibreOffice and the following is ignored but does not successfully convert the file):

```
'--headless -convert-to html:"""HTML (StarWriter)""" ' + path.replace(/"/g, '')
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nsIProcess` (Windows) will "escape" the arguments, that is:

- If an argument contains white-space then wrap it in `"` quotes.
- If an argument contains any `\` backspaces and or `"` quotes, then escape those with another `\`.

You're effectively double-escaping the `html:"HTML (StarWriter)"` string. Just use `html:HTML (StarWriter)`.

Another problem I encountered is that my copy of Libreoffice (4.2) will actually write the file to the current working directory, which in case of Firefox is usually `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox` and not writable. So better also provide an `-outdir`.

This worked in Scratchpad for me (note that I changed the paths from your code):

```
var Cc = Components.classes;
var Ci = Components.interfaces;

var sofficePath = ('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\LibreOffice 4\\program\\soffice.exe').replace(/"/g, '');
var path = 'C:\\Temp\\test.odt';
function createProcess (path, args) {
    var aNsIFile = Cc['@mozilla.org/file/local;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsILocalFile);
    aNsIFile.initWithPath(path);

    var process = Cc['@mozilla.org/process/util;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsIProcess);
    process.init(aNsIFile);
    process.runAsync(args, args.length, null);
}
createProcess(sofficePath, [
    '-headless', '-convert-to', 'html:HTML (StarWriter)', '-outdir', 'C:\\Temp', path.replace(/"/g, '')
]);
```

Producing this command line (watched in Process Monitor):

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program\soffice.exe" -headless -convert-to "html:HTML (StarWriter)" -outdir C:\Temp C:\temp\test.odt

Anyway, the `HTML (StarWriter)` filter is not actually necessary, just `html` works fine for me (and actually produces the same output).

Comment: Wow you are like the savior of SO ffaddon you type things out so well

Comment: Superb answer, indeed, thank you! (and that is high praise coming from @Noitidart ) One small point, however, is that testing on a ".doc", calling with just "html" as opposed to the `html:HTML (StarWriter)` returns XHTML 1.1 output which renders differently for me (and `html:` alone produces some binary gibberish).

Comment: For the record, `html` produced the better rendered code (everything ended up centered in my "StarWriter" conversion)